# Regular Expression for comma separated number ranging from 1-4 without repetition

Tags: regex, validation

I am making web application which takes test of end user in following way:

A question which have four option. A user must have to select from this four options only.

That question can have single option as answer or multiple options as answer. This questions are added from admin side. If question have answer in single option then radio button is shown and if multiple then checkbox is shown.

If the question have answer in multiple option then admin (while creating question from admin side of the web app) have to fill comma separated value in textbox of number ranging from 1 to 4.

I need to make sure that admin cannot insert values similar to following:

1,2,2 (no number should be repeated from 1-4)
1,2,3,
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,6,4
1,2,3,4,

while admin can enter
2,4,3
2
2,3,4,1
1,2,4
1,2,3,4
etc

I have this one but it allows repetition

```
^[1-4](,[1-4])*$
```

Please suggest me regular expression for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!.*\b([1-4])\b.*\b\1\b)[1-4](,[1-4])*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gV6uR3/1)